# To Myself vs for myself

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Which is correct: "to myself" or "for myself"?

As in "... a gift for/to myself"

Comment: We could use some context, any context.  I said that to myself and wrote it.  I wrote that not for myself but for the site.

Comment: @yosef baskin thanks. But how about 'a gift for myself or a gift to myself?' Both are correct or no?

Comment: Go ahead and redo your question to explain it. You could also remove "Hi...please" as polite but unneeded.  I bought a gift for myself is okay, but usually I bough myself a gift.  I would have to work hard to find a setting, not impossible, for a gift to myself.

Comment: Having poured the tea for my guests, I found that nothing remained for myself. In order to test my new electronic mailbox I sent a letter to myself.

Comment: @Rzt -- Both  **a gift _for_ myself** and **a gift _to_ myself** are correct -- ***depending on the context***.  Provide some context and we can tell you which to use.

Answer (score 3):

There's a difference in meaning.

In one case,

> I made myself a sandwich.

could be rewritten as

> I made a sandwich for myself.

But you would generally prefer the former (indirect object) form unless you needed to make things especially clear.

In a longer sentence, the latter form can be useful:

> I made sandwiches for my friends and myself.

In these examples, there is a purpose or benefit in making the sandwiches, and "for" explains or indicates the purpose, in this case, the recipient of the benefit.

In another case,

> I sent myself a postcard.

could be rewritten as

> I sent a postcard to myself.

This shows direction rather than reason. That is, it indicates the recipient of the postcard itself more than of some benefit of the postcard. Again, using the indirect object is more succinct, and slightly preferred.